# Sum of the series $ \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^{n-1} (2n-1)x^{2n-2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

**Question:** Sum of the series $1-3x^2+5x^4 - ... + (-1)^{n-1} (2n-1)x^{2n-2} = \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^{n-1} (2n-1)x^{2n-2}$

My first idea is to integrate to get $\int f(x) dx = x -x^3 + x^5 - ... + (-1)^{ n-1}x^{2n-1} = \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n-1} x^{2n-1}$. Now I am trying to modify this to a geometric form:

$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n-1} x^{2n-1}$$

Comment: $x^{2n-1} = x\cdot x^{2(n-1)}$

Comment: Nitpick: The title of the question is non-sensical. On the left hand side there is a finite sum. On the right there is an infinite sum (= a series). If you want to indicate an infinite sum using ellipsis, $\ldots$, they should be *in the end*.

Comment: Very well, it has been corrected.

Comment: @Daniel_Fischer, I think I got it now : $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} x(-x^2)^{n-1} = \frac{x}{1+x^2}$, and then differentiate?

Comment: I made a silly mistake in my answer, corrected it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had the right idea. Now,

$${\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-1}x^{2n-1}=\left(-\frac{1}{x}\right)\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n}x^{2n}=\left(-\frac{1}{x}\right)\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-x^2)^{n}}$$

Now, we get that this is a Geometric Series with ratio ${(-x^2)}$ - but the index starts from ${1}$, not ${0}$. Hence

$${=\left(-\frac{1}{x}\right)\frac{(-x^2)}{1-(-x^2)}=\frac{x}{1+x^2}}$$

Now simply differentiate this expression, giving

$${\frac{1-x^2}{(1+x^2)^2}}$$

Answer (score 1):

$1-3x^2+5x^4-...=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n-1}(2n-1)x^{2n-2}=\big( \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n-1}x^{2n-1}  \big)'=\big(\frac{-1}{x}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-x^2)^{n} \big)'=\big(\frac{-1}{x}\times (\frac{1}{1+x^2}-1) \big)'=\big(\frac{x}{1+x^2} \big)'=\frac{1-x^2}{(1+x^2)^2}$

when $|x|<1$

Comment: The index of the geometric series starts from ${1}$, not $0$ - hence the result is not just ${\frac{1}{1+x^2}}$ - it's ${\frac{-x^2}{1+x^2}}$

Comment: Shouldn't the answer result to $\frac{1-x^2}{(1+x^2)^2}$ for $|x| < 1$

Comment: @Riemann'sPointyNose thank you !

Comment: @Gio no problem buddy :)

Answer (score 0):

$x-x^3+x^5-x^7+\dots=\frac{x}{1+x^2}=\int f(x)\mathrm dx$,
$f(x)=\left(\frac{x}{x^2+1}\right)'=\frac{1-x^2}{(1+x^2)^2}$